# Where is the line drawn for ethical hackers using stolen credentials in their paid services?

Tags: passwords, penetration-test, ethics

When “ethical” hackers/pen testers harvest repositories of stolen credentials to then use them in pen testing for paying clients, what ethical boundaries are broken? 
If a lazy hacker leaves their captured credentials out on an insecure, public-facing server and then an “ethical” hacker grabs them for their own paid services, it seems to me that it's stealing already stolen goods.

What about a penetration tester taking credentials gathered from a paid/contracted job and adding them to a database to be used in future client jobs?

Comment: This seems like it would be better as two separate questions, as the basic assumptions are so different.

Comment: As for the legal aspects please ask at [law.se]. And as for the purely ethical aspects not covered by laws: if harm might be done to others then the line is passed for me but your ethics might vary.

Comment: In addition to having two *very* different scenarios in the same question, there is the question of how the previously stolen credentials are used. Using list of passwords with no associated username to crack a hash? Probably OK. Using a previously stolen username/password combo to access an employee's personal cell phone account for a sim swap to get around 2FA, without their knowledge or consent? Probably unethical (and illegal). In between? Depends.

Comment: I apologize for the seperate scenarios, I figured it would be easier to put them both under the same roof. To be more specfic, the company would have been in a contracted pentest job. Lets say they do a phishing campaign and receive 50 user/pass combos and add them to their company database. That contract concludes and they then enter a new contract with a different entity in the same regional area and use those previously harvested credentials in their pentest efforts.

Comment: I removed the legal part, leaving a pure ethics question.

Comment: By "credentials" do you mean username/password pairs? Note that usernames are protected by various privacy laws and keeping people's live credentials as a pentester poses various liabilities.

Comment: Yes, user/pass pairs.